# ¿Forzar modo paisaje con plyr.io en celulares?

Tags: javascript, html, video

Hola comunidad quisiera resolver un problema, actualmente estoy utilizando plyr.io como reproductor, el detalle es que cuando se quiere ver un vídeo en un celular, habrá alguna manera para que al darle al botón para maximizar detecte tamaño de la pantalla y si es necesario se ponga modo paisaje (landscape) y no solo en retrato como es el problema

### [image: 1]]

Este es el código, desde antemano gracias:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Plyr</title>
  <!-- Plyr style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.1.0/plyr.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Plyr -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.1.0/plyr.min.js"></script>

  <video id="player" controls crossorigin>
  </video>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const player = new Plyr('#player');
  player.source = {
    type: 'video',
    title: 'Sintel',
    sources: [{
        src: '//iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/video/sintel-short.webm',
        type: 'video/mp4',
      }

    ],
    tracks: [{
        kind: 'captions',
        label: 'English',
        srclang: 'en',
        src: '//iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/subtitles/vtt/sintel-en.vtt',
        default: false,
      },
      {
        kind: 'captions',
        label: 'German',
        srclang: 'de',
        src: '//iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player-with-captions/subtitles/vtt/sintel-de.vtt',
      },
    ],
  };
</script>

</html>
```